# Problem with the jquery live() function and AJAX-loaded content

Tags: html, ajax, dom, jquery

i have a little problem with jquery for an interaction design trick i'm implementing. I have a link and a hidden drop-down menu to show when the user clicks on the link. I want the dropdown menu to hide if the user clicks out of the link or menu. Both of these elements are on the portion of a page loaded dynamically with AJAX (hence the use of the live() function). Everything works fine if I do it on a non AJAX-reloaded container, but doesn't work as soon as it's a dynamically loaded content (the dropdown menu shows, but doesn't hide if i click outside). My code is the following:

```
$("#clickToOpen").live('click',function(event) {
    $("#dropdownMenu").show();
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("#dropdownMenu").live('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).live('click',function() {
    $("#dropdownMenu").hide(); 
});
```

(i also tried with the click() function directly for the last event on (document), since this element is not reloaded, but doesn't work)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

i feel you can create a class  like

```
.hide {
display:none;
}
```

and use a toggleClass like this...

```
$("#clickToOpen").live('click',function(event) {
$('#dropdownMenu').toggleClass("hide");
})
```

not a tested code...

here is the final code for u ...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
.hide {
display:none;
}

.show {
display:visible;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a href='' id='clickToOpen'>click me</a>

<div id='dropdownMenu' class='hide'>dropdownMenu</div>

<script>
$("#clickToOpen").live('click',function(event) {
$('#dropdownMenu').toggleClass("hide");
event.preventDefault();
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone should correct me if I am wrong.

But for my understanding of `.live` calling `event.stopPropagation()` will have no effect at all as, for live to work it is attached to the window or document object, hence, it has propagated as far as it can already.

With regards to the hiding the menu,

I believe you should look into adding a transparent overlay, the same sort of thing as modal dialogs use.

Then you are binding to the overlay to hide the menu.